# Fresh Windows 10 install of anaconda and jupyter - Kernel Error (Python 2.7 and 3.5)

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10, jupyter, python-3.5, jupyter-notebook

I have been using ipython and also a little bit of jupyter for quite some time, some time ago. After not having used it in almost 6 months I wanted to start using it again.

I installed the newest version of jupyter, updated my python 2.7 install, got pip working and installed the necessary packages:

```
pip install jupyter
pip install notebook
```

and etc. After having done that I tried to enter an old notebook (written in 2.7) but there was no connection to the kernel. I thought, well wth, why not just update to the newest python 3 version and try that. That resulted in the same problem.

I went ahead and installed anaconda and created two virtual envs, one with python 2.7 and one with python 3.5. Both installed like this:

```
conda create --name py27 python=2.7 anaconda
conda create --name py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

After that I made sure that both venvs had jupyter installed by activating them and trying to install the package. (This was done with py27 and py35 which are the names of the venvs as seen from above commands).

```
activate py27
conda install jupyter
```

After that I tried to run:

```
jupyter notebook
```

I created a new notebook file to see if I had access to the kernel. However it was made clear that I didn't with the following error:

[image: jupyter first run in a new notebook]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 458, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1014, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 58, in post
    sm.create_session(path=path, kernel_name=kernel_name))
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1014, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 73, in create_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 282, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 87, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 109, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 244, in start_kernel**kw)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 190, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 108, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__ restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This was obviously tried on my py35 venv however I get the same error on my py27 venv. I have tried a few things such as running the kernelspec, but none of it to any success.

Someone got a suggestion to what might be wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35697794/ipython-kernel-error-after-uninstalling-anaconda

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to create a kernelspec for the jupyter notebook. Follow this link to solve it.

[How to start an ipython shell(not notebook) within a conda or virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956278/how-to-start-an-ipython-shellnot-notebook-within-a-conda-or-virtualenv)