# using a conda virtual environment in jupyter notebook

Tags: ipython, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have read and implemented instructions from earlier posts like:

[How to start an ipython shell(not notebook) within a conda or virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956278/how-to-start-an-ipython-shellnot-notebook-within-a-conda-or-virtualenv)

My goal is to use a kernel in ipython which has all conda packages from my virtual environment. 
I have a google ubuntu 16.04 machine where I have installed anaconda and a virtual environment in which i installed all my packages..

when i run

```
python -m ipykernel.kernelspec
```

i get the following error:

```
/home/admin/anaconda3/envs/py36ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/paths.py:61: UserWarning: IPython dir 
'/home/admin/.ipython' is not a writable location, using a temp 
directory.
  " using a temp directory.".format(ipdir))
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3'
```

I tried running with sudo too.. i created a kernel but when i use it then it has none of the packages i installed in the virtual environment..

Answer (score 1):

I do have a similar issue with this when I try to submit my program to a cluster where it doesn't have access to my local directory and it shows the same message. But I don't get `Permission denied` message and everything is fine by me. But I wanted to address this issue and looked into it and I found that [paths.py](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/paths.py) at line **62** in `python` package in the case of `not writable`, it creates a temp directory like the following:

```
    ipdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
```

As in [**tempfile** documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) says:

> Creates a temporary directory in the most secure manner possible. There are no race conditions in the directory’s creation. The directory is readable, writable, and searchable only by the creating user ID.

It is strange that you do get this but if you  want to make it work, find the `paths.py` and change that to your liking and makes sure it works and replace it with the original.