# How to start correctly a ipython within conda environment?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

My question is opposite with this one : [How to start an ipython shell(not notebook) within a conda or virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956278/how-to-start-an-ipython-shellnot-notebook-within-a-conda-or-virtualenv)

I have Anaconda installed, and I created an environment called `myenv`.

Then:

```
source activate myenv
conda install package_x
ipython notebook
```

And I opened the browser followed the given link, and start a new notebook. It turns out that the notebook kernel is not `myenv` - it does not have the packages that I installed in `myenv`.

How to let start an ipython notebook with the kernel belongs to `myenv`?

Thanks

Comment: Install the `ipykernel` package, and change the kernel in the Notebook; or install the notebook package and launch `jupyter notebook` (not ipython)