# check which conda env jupyter console is using

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-console

I have a conda environment and I would like to run a jupyter console within that environment. I do the usual `source activate myenv` and then `jupyter console`. The `source activate myenv` works since `which python` points to the right path. However, it doesn't seem like the `jupyter console` is picking up the right env. I have done this:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```

I have `nb_conda` and `nb_conda_kernels` installed. What's going on with my setup? I have Ipython 6.4.0, Python 3.6.5. Also, coming from an R background, I find it weird that I'm spending so much time on the basic setup where in R things just work. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong? How can i check which env Ipython is running in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.executable` does indeed give you that info. This is how one should actually start the correct kernel (provided by [How to start an ipython shell(not notebook) within a conda or virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956278/how-to-start-an-ipython-shellnot-notebook-within-a-conda-or-virtualenv)):

```
source activate myenv
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "myenv"
jupyter console --kernel myenv
```

To get a list of the kernels that can be used:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

Comment: If you answered your question, you should accept it so that people can find the solution when they encounter this problem. Glad you made progress!

Comment: Good feature. :)

Comment: yeh, pretty odd

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Your conda environment is just a unique interpreter executable with its own PATH, etc. You could then regex on the string of its location to get the environment name.

Comment: The value of ``sys.prefix`` would usually give the root directory of a virtual environment. If conda env are similar you just need to take last segment of path from that. Possibly easier to determine from that than ``sys.executable``.

Comment: Indeed, either will work. `sys.prefix.split('\')[-1]` or `sys.executable.split('\')[-2]` should return the name of your `env`.

Comment: yes, `sys.executable` is pointing to the wrong interpreter.. how can i change that? so i just manually set sys.executable?